# Python Meteostat stations keeps throwing error

Tags: python, database, api

I'm trying to pull daily bulk data from meteostat using their library but I keep getting the same error relating to the station.

Here's my code

```py
from meteostat import Stations, Daily
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Get closest weather station to Birmingham, AL
stations = Stations(lat = 33.52068, lon = -86.81176)
station = stations.fetch(1)

# Get daily data for 2020 at the selected weather station
data = Daily(station, start = datetime(2020, 10, 1), end = datetime(2020, 10, 15))
data = data.fetch()

# Plot line chart including average, minimum and maximum temperature
data.plot(x = 'time', y = ['tavg', 'tmin', 'tmax'], kind = 'line')
plt.show()
```

Which is almost exactly what they have in their docs, but I keep getting this error:

*File "api_connect.py", line 26, in 
stations = Stations(lat = 33.52068, lon = -86.81176)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/meteostat/stations.py", line 75, in **init**
file = self._load(['stations/lib.csv.gz'])[0]
IndexError: list index out of range*

I haven't altered *stations.py* at all.

Any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code on my machine and it works for me.

The error means that the library cannot save the list of weather stations locally. This was definitely a bug in the 0.1.0 release of the library. You should first make sure that you're on the latest release by running:

```
pip install meteostat -U
```

If that doesn't solve the problem, you can check if the `~/.meteostat/cache` directory is created correctly and add the directory manually if it doesn't exist yet. Otherwise, you can also define a custom location for Meteostat to save your files into as described in the [documentation](https://dev.meteostat.net/python/configuration.html#cache-directory).

Comment: I had same issue as OP and it was the cache. Looks like the link is outdated, but this works as of 4/19/21: https://dev.meteostat.net/python/api/stations/#attributes

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue as OP and it was the cache, as Christian mentions above.

You can set the cache like this:

```
from meteostat import Stations

Stations.cache_dir = '/my/path/goes/here'

stations = Stations()
```

I got this from this link:
https://dev.meteostat.net/python/api/stations/#attributes